# How to interpolate and smooth data with step-like values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwwhEMUIYGyTSm9vdERxSnF2R28) in step-like manner shown in figure, which I am trying to interpolate with Python with the MWE, but I get the error:

[image]

**ERROR**

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 54, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 448, in _evaluate
    out_of_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 478, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "
ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.`

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize, interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import time


with open('./pdf_data.dat', "r") as data:
    while True:
        line = data.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            break
    data_header = [i for i in line.strip().split('\t') if i]
    _data_ = np.genfromtxt(data, names = data_header, dtype = None, delimiter = '\t')
_data_.dtype.names = [j.replace('_', ' ') for j in _data_.dtype.names]


x = _data_['X']
y = _data_['Y']


interp_fn = interp1d(x, y)
x, index = np.unique(x, return_index = True)


pdf_interp = interp_fn(x)
```

How to interpolate and smoothen step-like values in Python? Such that I get a smooth curve.

Comment: It looks like you haven't included the entirety of the error backtrace -- it only goes as far back as `scipy/interpolate/polyint.py` and doesn't show us where in *your* code the error happens. Is it when you call `interp_fn` at the end of the code you've listed, or is it somewhere else?

Comment: When you construct your `interp1d` object, you can pass in `bounds_error=False, fill_value="extrapolate"` and then instead of complaining about out-of-range values you'll get extrapolations. Whether that's a good idea depends on just how far out of range they actually are.

Comment: Seems that your `np.unique` has no effect here

Comment: *If* the error is happening when you say `pdf_interp = interp_fn(x)` then, given that those are the *same* `x` values you passed to `interp1d`, it seems like any out-of-bounds-ness you're seeing must be extremely small (e.g., the result of some kind of rounding error). But if it's actually happening somewhere else, you might be trying to do a more substantial extrapolation...

Answer (score 0):

Can reproduce your error simply by:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f = interp1d([1,2,3,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5])
f([1,2,3,4])  # prints [1,2,3,5], note that the 3rd value is not as you may expect
f([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Error message of the last command `f([1,2,3,4,5])`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\winPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py", line 79, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)
  File "C:\winPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 497, in _evaluate
    out_of_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
  File "C:\winPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 527, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "
ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.
```

So please print out the `x` value in your script and see whether it contains out-of-range value.

Since you used `np.unique` in the code, it seems that you need to call `interp_fn(equivalence_ratio)` instead of `interp_fn(x)`

```
x1, index = np.unique(x, return_index = True)
y1 = [y[k] for k in index]
interp_fn = interp1d(x1, y1)
pdf_interp = interp_fn(x)
```

This code works fine well with the data file you attached.

Comment: This may reproduce the error, but it is a bad example of `interp1d` usage - you have duplicated the `x` values when you call `interp1d`.  Even though the function doesn't reject the bad input, it does affect the output, and can cause unpredictable interpolation results.

Comment: I assume the data of the @nxkryptor contains a large number of duplicated values. That's the key point of this question.

Comment: Indeed it does. (I think mostly because of over-aggressive rounding -- all the numbers in the data file are given to only three significant figures.)

Comment: @gdlmx: you can also reproduce the error with `f=interp1d([1,2], [3,4]); f(3)`